# d3.v3 transitions happening instantly?

Tags: d3.js, transition, bar-chart

I've recently passed from d3.v2 to d3.v3, and am trying to understand the differences in the transition mechanisms.

In the code underneath, I'm trying to make a bar graph that, when drawn, has bars that increase in height via a transition. This code works without issue in d3.v2, but in v3, the transition seems to happen "instantly" (the height is immediately set to the end value).

```
graph.enter()//for each bucket
.append('g')
.attr('transform',function(d,i){  return 'translate('+(xBand(i))+')';}) 
.attr('width',xBand.rangeBand())
.each(function(data,index){//here we are working on the selection for a single bucket
        var $this=d3.select(this); //this refers to the group selection
        var currentY=0;
        var rects=$this.selectAll('rect')
            .data(data.values);

        rects.enter()
        .insert('rect')
        .attr('group-id',me.groupId)
            .attr('y',Hats.accessor('y'))
        .attr('width',xBand.rangeBand())
        .attr('fill',(function(elt){ return me.colors(me.groupId(elt));}));

        rects.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr('height',(function(elt){ 
            var h=_.compose(heightScale,me.values)(elt);
                d3.select(this).attr('y',currentY);
                currentY+=h;
                return h;
        }));
});
```

Comment: have you tried adding a delay to the transition?

Comment: Did you try on different browsers ?

Comment: @rysloan I've tried adding a delay, and nothing changed

Comment: @LoremIpsum chrome and firefox both show the same behavior

Comment: A fun extra point: When I try to change the color attribute, the transition does work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a starting height in your enter selection:

```
rects.enter()
    .insert('rect')
    .attr('group-id',me.groupId)
    .attr('y',Hats.accessor('y'))
    .attr('width',xBand.rangeBand())
    .attr('fill',(function(elt){ return me.colors(me.groupId(elt));}))
    .attr('height', 0);

rects.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr('height',(function(elt){ 
        var h=_.compose(heightScale,me.values)(elt);
            d3.select(this).attr('y',currentY);
            currentY+=h;
            return h;
    }));
```